# Setting Radio button default value from state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vuejs application, during login, I get all the user's settings in my vuex state.

One of the settings `defaultView` can have a value of either 1 or 2 depending on the user's selection.

I get this value from the state:

```
  ...mapGetters({
      'defaultView'
  })
```

I'm my data hook I have this:

```
data () {
   return {
     selected: defaultView ? defaultView : 2
   }
}
```

but selected is always 2, ignoring the value of `defaultView`.

I have tried using the mounted hook to set the value, but on page refresh, it loses the value.

How do I set the default value of selected from the state object?

Comment: Computed properties are added to the component *after* the data properties are added. You cannot reference a computed property in the data function. Beyond that, if it *could* work, it would be `this.defaultView`.

Comment: that is what I figured. but now I don't know how else to set the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value in `created`.

```
created(){
  this.selected = this.defaultView || 2
}
```

Comment: This works on initial load, but I the user press F5, the value changes to whatever is in the data function.

Comment: @capiono F5 refreshes the page entirely typically, which means that the entire app just got reloaded.